# Visual Studio Code with Bash Terminal (WSL) in C++ builds only .out files - not .exe

Tags: c++, bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 with the Linux Subsystem. (Ubuntu)

I've created a small c++ file and when I'm building it with the bash terminal - only a .out file is created. Which is fine, but I want to debug it as well and in that case - I can only open .exe files.

When I switch to powershell from bash - the build extension is an .exe

```
tasks.json

{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
        "-g", "main.cpp"
      ],
      "group": { "kind": "build", "isDefault": true }
    }
  ]
}

launch.json for debugging 

{
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe", // .out doesn't work here
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "preLaunchTask": "echo",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }

main.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "hello a" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm really not sure what to do - as I'm not able to debug .out files and I'd like to choose the build extension myself.

Comment: You are invoking g++ from a linux machine (WSL terminal is roughly a linux virtual machine), so it generates a linux-compatible binary. If you want it to generate a binary for a different machine such as your windows machine, you have to do cross compilation (I've never done it myself, but compilers tend to support it)

Comment: Thank you @Justin - found the solution thanks to your cross-compilation tip.

Comment: g++ -g main.cpp -o main.exe right?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

And then inside tasks.json

```
"command": "i686-w64-mingw32-g++"
```

That compiles a 32 bit exe - but the 64 bit version with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` somehow doesn't work. Creates an invalid exe.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run/debug cross-platform, your have to use cross-compilers such as MinGW. You can install **MinGW-w64** in both Windows, Linux (or WSL).

**VScode-tools** with gdb.exe from MinGW can debug `*.out` as well as `*.exe` files (Tested).

To compile 64-bit version you need to include some static depedency library for C/C++ which are *libgcc* and *libstdc++* while compile. so the `command` and `args` in task.json should be:

```
"command": "x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++",
"args": [
           "-g",                  //Need for debug and compatibility
           "-static-libgcc",      //flag for the libgcc
           "-static-libstdc++",   //flag for the libgc++
           "helloworld.cpp",      //C++ source code
           "-o",                  //flag for output
           "a2.out"               //Output filename and extension (can be .exe) 
            ],
```

You can learn more about C/C++ Standard Library Dependencies [here](http://arrayfire.com/cross-compile-to-windows-from-linux/)